# Getting parent repository path

Tags: mercurial

I have a cloned mercurial repository (and working copy) in my own machine. Is it possible if I want to know the parent path to a specific file? For example, I cloned a repository that contains a file at

```
http://foo/bar/hgwebdir.cgi/repository/file_a
```

and file_a is located in my machine at

```
/home/jeffrey04/documents/repository_clone/file_a
```

Is there a command that I can use to get the parent path (the first url) of file_a ??!

Answer (score 7):

`hg paths` will show the repository path, and `hg root` your current repository.  I think you'd have to do the path munging yourself, however.

I understand hg extensions can be as simple as a python file, so might be easy to write yourself.